# Unable to get a list of mattermost channels in golang

Tags: api, go, mattermost

I am trying to create a bot and retrieve the list of channels.
I used the [bot example](https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-bot-sample-golang/blob/master/bot_sample.go) in repository and it is mostly working, except for the part where it has to get the list of channels.

Either I am doing something silly or [GetChannels API](https://godoc.org/github.com/mattermost/platform/model#Client.GetChannels) really does not work the way it is described in bot_sample.go .
I made a smaller [separate function](https://gist.github.com/prateeksriv/65093eb187edf56bfacebabbf32abfea) to test that part.

Adding code here for better readability:

```
func mattermostPrintChannels(client *mattermost.Client) {
    channelsResult, err := client.GetChannels("")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("Couldn't get channels: ", err)
        return
    }
    channelList := channelsResult.Data.(*mattermost.ChannelList)
    fmt.Print("Channels:")
    for _, channel := range channelList.Channels {
        fmt.Printf("%s -> %s", channel.Id, channel.DisplayName)
    }
}
```

This code gives me the error:

> ./mattermost.go:30: channelList.Channels undefined (type
>   *model.ChannelList has no field or method Channels)

Now if I just print the contents of ChannelList variable (using spew), I get the following:

```
channelList:  :  ([]interface {}) (len=1 cap=1) {
 (*model.ChannelList)(<nil>)
}
```

Comment: It's likely that the example you're looking at is just old and out of date. Looking at the docs, [`ChannelList`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mattermost/platform/model#ChannelList) is a `[]*Channel` slice, so just range over that.

Answer (score 0):

JimB is correct. The `model.ChannelList` type used to be a struct, but it recently changed to `[]*model.Channel`. You'll want to change

```
for _, channel := range channelList.Channels {
```

to

```
for _, channel := range *channelList {
```